# How to install a docker inside another docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using a docker installation inside centos version '7' Linux environment.
I need to run a Dockerfile that can run only in ubuntu '14.04' version.

I have pulled an ubuntu image inside centos Linux. And obviously, I can't directly run docker commands inside that ubuntu image.

So, I tried setting up a docker installation inside ubuntu image but it fails stating that docker.io package not found.(And, it doesn't even make any sense because docker is installed above OS. All Linux uses same kind of OS and their application soft is what makes them different)

I have learn a bit about **docker.sock** that can help you setup a docker inside docker container.
**How can I use this concept in here ?**

**Note : I had recently started learning docker concepts. So, don't have much experience on it**

**Error**

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden 
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden 

W: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-infra-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: XXXX]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: XXXX]
```

Comment: If you're trying to run an image `FROM ubuntu:14.04`, you should be able to run it independently of the host OS.  You don't need a second installation of Docker anywhere, and the host and container distributions don't need to match.  Just `docker run` the image as normal.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze , this is what I need to do
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337
The only difference is, I am using centos linux and I want to run docker commands in ubuntu.
I also tried the following command mention in the above link but I am getting errors(updated in post)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same issue by manually installing docker inside my container as per the following docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 # Or any other base image

# https://medium.com/@schogini/running-docker-inside-and-outside-of-a-jenkins-container-along-with-docker-compose-a-tiny-c908c21557aa

USER root

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz | tar xvz -C /tmp/ && mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/bin/docker

# Customize here your container...
```

Don't forget to map the host `/var/run/docker.sock` file by:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...some other command arguments...
```

Doing so we install a fresh docker CLI inside the docker image which share the `docker.sock` file with the host OS.

Comment: Hi Antonio, I didn't understand. If I build this, how would it setup a docker inside a ubuntu image ?  (Sorry, if it's a stupid question)

Comment: Sure, I updated the post with further information. I use it everyday.

Comment: I tried same thing, but getting some errors like Failed to fetch binary-amd64 packages. See the error details in the post

Comment: @AntonioPetricca- I assume you are trying to execute a jenkins pipeline that builds and/or publishes the docker image of an maven spring boot app. I am trying to do the same but I am facing multiple errors. Would it be possible for you to share the Jenkinsfile script too?

Comment: Sorry, but it not possibile due to disclosure agreement reasons.

Comment: Ok np. I am stuck on the docker image to be used for jenkins pipeline for it to build & push the docker image through the spring-boot-maven-plugin (spring-boot:build-image command). This docker image needs to have jdk, maven and docker installed within it. What image did you use in your jenkins pipeline? Thanks!